# Is it possible to use a trained sklearn.mixture.GMM model with C++ for iOS?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have an established model that I'm trying to extend to an iOS app.

Ultimately I would like to train the model on the server, and then be able to score a feature vector on the device rather than making a call to the server each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it involves...math. It will involve computing the probabilities of membership manually using the coefficients determined by the scikit-learn model (`weights_, means_, covars_, converged_`).

You will need to understand exactly what your particular GMM model is doing (possibly dig up the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn)) in the 'predict' method, then use the data members of your model (see the [attributes section of the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM)).

I realize this is not a detailed answer, but what I just described is what I would have to do to come up with a math/code formula for you to follow.